# np.arange［0, 1.01, 0.01］で配列を作りたい

Tags: python, python3, numpy, array

掲題の通り `np.arange[0,1.01,0.01]` の101個の配列を複数個作って
インデックスで例えば

```
[1]np.arange[0,1.01,0.01]
[2]np.arange[0,1.01,0.01]
[3]np.arange[0,1.01,0.01]
   ...
[k]np.arange[0,1.01,0.01]
```

という具合に配列を作りたいのですが、どうしたらよいかわかりません。
どなたかご教授願えませんか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記のスクリプトでいかがでしょうか
np.arange(0,1.01,0.01)でできる配列をk個配列に詰め込んだものになります

```
k=5     
a = [np.arange(0,1.01,0.01) for _ in range(k)]
```

結果としては下記のようになります

```
 array([0.  , 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 ,
       0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 , 0.21,
       0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3 , 0.31, 0.32,
       0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.41, 0.42, 0.43,
       0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.5 , 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54,
       0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.6 , 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65,
       0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.7 , 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76,
       0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 , 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87,
       0.88, 0.89, 0.9 , 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98,
       0.99, 1.  ]), array([0.  , 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 ,
       0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2 , 0.21,
       0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3 , 0.31, 0.32,
       0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.41, 0.42, 0.43,
       0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.5 , 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54,
       0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.6 , 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 0.65,
       0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.7 , 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 0.76,
       0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8 , 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 0.87,
       0.88, 0.89, 0.9 , 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 0.98,
       0.99, 1.  ])...]
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。この101個の配列を5個作るにはa[5]とすればよいのでしょうか？素人質問で申し訳ないです。

Comment: 5個というよりk番目といったほうがいいのですが、その場合はどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: range(101)の部分で101個の配列を作成するという処理になりますので、range(k)としていただければ大丈夫です

Comment: すいませんちょっと違うような気がするので追加です。これをfor k in range(M) for i in range(N)  X[k][i]のようにしたいのですがどうでしょうか？

Comment: 例に挙げた配列ですと例えば、a[k][i]とするとk番目のnp.arange(0,1.01,0.01)配列のi番目の要素を指すことになります

Comment: codeZ様　上のコードを使っているのですが、a[k][i]として取り出したいのですが、 xupper[k][i] = [np.arange(0,1.01,0.01) for _ in range(k)]としてコンパイルすると、ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.となってしまいます。対処法があれば教えていただきたいのですが。

Comment: xupper = [np.arange(0,1.01,0.01) for _ in range(k)]
としてから xupper[k][i]を参照してください

Comment: うまくいきました。